# Why does my directory in public_html disappear if i use the "RewriteEngine on" directive in the .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I'm experiencing a strange problem since the last ubuntu update of my development machine with the apache2 userdir. I have a PHP project in the apache2 userdir located in  /home/myUser/public_html/project/. In the project folder, i have an .htaccess file with the "RewriteEngine on" directive.

If if comment the directive, the browser shows me the folder on entering localhost/~myUser/ as he should. But if i use the directive, localhost/~myUser/project/ disappears. If i try to enter it by typing the URL manually, i get an "Not Found" error. Any ideas why?

Im Using Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 5.5.3.

/EDIT: The problem is not the "RewriteEngine on" but the "RewriteRule". Commenting that out also shows the project directory again.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine   on

RewriteRule     ^(.*)$  /~myUser/project/php/$1   [P]

php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 33M
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

content of the userdir.conf:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
        #AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        AllowOverride all
        Options MultiViews Indexes FollowSymlinks IncludesNoExec
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you share more details on your .htaccess content? also, can you check your default directory settings, by default it is set to deny access.

Comment: i have added the .htaccess content and the directory statement of the userdir.conf, was it that what you mean?

Comment: Do you have a "php" directory inside your project directory? I'm asking because you don't mention such directory, and your rule is using that directory. This could be the source of the issue.

Comment: Yes there is one. It's containing the index.php and the other code for the Web app.

Comment: Just figured out that removing the [P]-Flag also helps - no idea why! The proxy mods for apache2 are installed.